# Reading from file.txt to array of strings and using it to play Conway's game of Life

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I am coding a Conway's Game of Life.My task is  reading from file.txt to array of strings.And then using this array as the input array of the game. I have written a code about it. But it is full of error. I don't know what is the correct way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
namespace gamearray {
  int main() 


    ifstream file_("file.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string myArray[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

            file >> array1[j][i];
        }
    }
return 0; 
}

void copy(int array1[10][10], int array2[10][10])
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            array2[j][i] = array1[j][i];
    }
}


void life(int array[10][10], char choice)
{

  int temp[10][10];
  copy(array, temp);
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(choice == 'm')
            {

                int count = 0;
                count = array[j-1][i] +
                    array[j-1][i-1] +
                    array[j][i-1] +
                    array[j+1][i-1] +
                    array[j+1][i] +
                    array[j+1][i+1] +
                    array[j][i+1] +
                    array[j-1][i+1];

        if(count < 2 || count > 3)
                    temp[j][i] = 0;

        if(count == 2)
                    temp[j][i] = array[j][i];

        if(count == 3)
                    temp[j][i] = 1;
            }


        }
    }

  copy(temp, array);
}


bool compare(int array1[10][10], int array2[10][10])
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(array1[j][i]==array2[j][i])
                count++;
        }
    }

    if(count == 10*10)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}


void print(int array[10][10])
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(array[j][i] == 1)
                cout << '*';
            else
                cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{gamearray::main(); 

int gen0[10][10];
int todo[10][10];
int backup[10][10];
char neighborhood;
char again;
char cont;
bool comparison;


{do
    {

  do
        {
    cout << "Which neighborhood would you like to use (m): ";
          cin >> neighborhood;
        }while(neighborhood != 'm');

  system("CLS");
  int i = 0;

  do
        {

            srand(time(NULL));

            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    gen0[j][i] = rand() % 2;
            }



    if(i == 0)
                copy(gen0, todo);
            copy(todo, backup);
            print(todo);
          life(todo, neighborhood);
          i++;


    system("sleep .5");

    if(i % 10 == 1 && i != 1)
    {
      cout << endl;

      do
      {
        cout << "Would you like to continue this simulation? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cont;
      }while(cont != 'y' && cont != 'n');
      if(cont == 'n')
        break;
    }

    comparison = compare(todo, backup);
    if(comparison == false)
      system("CLS");
    if(comparison == true)
      cout << endl;
        }while(comparison == false);
  do
     {
       cout << "Would you like to run another simulation? (y/n): ";
          cin >> again;
     }while(again != 'y' && again != 'n');
    }while(again == 'y');

    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error messages?

Comment: TDD (TestDrivenDevelopment) should be your friend here. Decompose problem/code into functions and test them idependently. You will find bugs and fix your code. It could be much faster way than attaching debbuger or starving at code :)

Comment: Why do you put `main` inside namespace gamearray? Why do you polute the global namespace with `using namespace std`? Why is there no opening brace `{` after `main()`? (Does this even compile?), You may want to learn about `else if`,  `else` after an `if` that always returns is pretty redundant, You could work on your formating (recommend [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)), don't use `system`; please, there's lots more to point out - I guess the best advice is: read a *good* C++ book (or two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aftert main you are missing {
in first and second loop you have i loop twice

why do you need to copy ?

you can use this function fscanf() to read your file

e.g.

```
File= fopen(FileName, "r");
             if( File == NULL ){
            printf("Impossible to open  file %s ! \n",FileName);
        }

if( File != NULL)
{
   char text[255];
   while(!feof(File))
   {
      fscanf(File,"%s\n",&text);
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the task given to me. My code must read a text.file as an array and this array should be used as the input of the code.

Comment: you declare  string mArray[10]  but you use array[][] why?

Comment: 14 expected initializer before 'ifstream' 15 expected unqualified-id before if these are the errors

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * spielm.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 22.09.2016
 *      Author: fislam
 */


    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;


    void GetFile();
    bool MakeArray();
    char ChgArray();
    //char GameBoard();

    const int ROW1 =10;
    const int COL1 =10;
    const int BOARD_ROWS(10);
    const int BOARD_COLS(10);
    ifstream myfile;
    string filename;
    char live = 'X';
    char dead = '.';

    char board [BOARD_ROWS][BOARD_COLS];

    int main()
    {
        int q;

        //GetFile();
        if ( MakeArray() ){

          for ( int i(0); i <10; i++)
             ChgArray();
        }
        else {
          cout << "Error parsing input file" << endl;
        }

        cin >> q;
        return 0;
    }


    void GetFile()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the filename: \n";
        cin>>filename;
        return;
    }

    bool MakeArray()
    {
        bool ret(false);
        char val;
        int  totCnt = BOARD_ROWS*BOARD_COLS;
        myfile.open (/*filename.c_str()*/"c_str.txt");
        if ( myfile.is_open() ) {
           for (int r=0; r<ROW1; r++)
           {
              for (int c=0; c<COL1; c++)
              {
                 myfile>>val;
                 if ( val == dead || val == live ) {
                    board[r-1][c-1] = val;
                    totCnt--;
                 }
              }
           }
           if ( !totCnt ) {
             ret = true;
           }
           myfile.close();
        }
return ret;
    }
    char getNextState(char b[BOARD_ROWS][BOARD_COLS], int r, int c)
    {
       char ret;

       return ret;
    }
    char ChgArray()
    {
        char boardTmp[BOARD_ROWS][BOARD_COLS];
        for (int r=0; r<BOARD_ROWS; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<BOARD_COLS; c++)
            {

                boardTmp[r][c] = getNextState(board,r,c);

                cout << boardTmp[r][c];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

        memcpy(board,boardTmp,sizeof(board));
        cout << endl;

    }
```

Instead of the previous I wrote new. and it worked